# Azure ACS with HTTPS and multiple instances Error

Tags: azure, acs

I just followed the following instructions [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Azure/IdentityAzure/WIFonWAZLab/Exercise-1-Enabling-Federated-Authentication-for-ASPNET-applications-in-Windows-Azure).

And found a couple blog entries [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2011/03/17/windows-azure-web-role-asp-net-application-federated-authentication-using-appfabric-access-control-service-acs-v2-part-1.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidmcg/archive/2011/04/05/publishing-a-acs-v2-federated-identity-web-role.aspx) to be rather helpful.

But I am still getting weird issues with my ASP.NET MVC3 app running on Azure on an HTTPS end point. I have the HTTPS certificate loaded and it has deployed consistently on a single role instance for quite some time without any issue. However, just recently I started deploying multiple instances and ran into the 'Key not valid for use in specified state' and the 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: certificate' erors.

But I have a new one now:

'Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.'

Looks pretty vanilla. It doesn't become obvious that its an issue with the move from DPAPI to the RSA cookie transform until you look at the stack trace.

> [EndOfStreamException: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.]
>      System.IO.MemoryStream.InternalReadInt32() +12750266
>      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.RsaEncryptionCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[] encoded) +369
>      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte[] cookie, Boolean outbound) +189
>      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +862
>      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(Byte[] token, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +109
>      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.ReadSessionTokenFromCookie(Byte[] sessionCookie) +356
>      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken& sessionToken) +123
>      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +61
>      System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +270

I have added the following code to global.asax:

```
    void OnServiceConfigurationCreated(object sender, ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e) 
    {  
        // 
        // Use the <serviceCertificate> to protect the cookies that are sent to the client. 
        // 
        List<CookieTransform> sessionTransforms = new List<CookieTransform>(
            new CookieTransform[] { 
                new DeflateCookieTransform(), 
                new RsaEncryptionCookieTransform(e.ServiceConfiguration.ServiceCertificate) }); 
        SessionSecurityTokenHandler sessionHandler = new SessionSecurityTokenHandler(sessionTransforms.AsReadOnly());  
        e.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace(sessionHandler); 
    }
```

As well as this code:

```
    void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider(object sender, RedirectingToIdentityProviderEventArgs e)  
    { 
        // In the Windows Azure environment, build a wreply parameter for the SignIn request 
        // that reflects the real address of the application. 
        HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;  
        Uri requestUrl = request.Url; 
        StringBuilder wreply = new StringBuilder();  
        wreply.Append(requestUrl.Scheme); // e.g. "http" or "https" 
        wreply.Append("://"); 
        wreply.Append(request.Headers["Host"] ?? requestUrl.Authority); 
        wreply.Append(request.ApplicationPath);  
        if (!request.ApplicationPath.EndsWith("/")) wreply.Append("/"); e.SignInRequestMessage.Reply = wreply.ToString();   
    }
```

Comment: I am also having this problem. It's very frustrating - if you've found a solution, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on similar problem and the potential reason was combination of older SDK and ACS. If you try using SDK 1.6 and ACSv2 setting, i hope this problem will not occur and if you still see the problem, I would be glad to work with you to root cause it.